# Angular and Material doesn't load style

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created my angular project with the angular cli. After that I followed this guide https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Now everything is in place I created a material module like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MatButtonModule],
  exports: [MatButtonModule],
})
export class MyOwnMaterialModule { }
```

In my app.component.ts I imported my MyOwnMaterialModule like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyOwnMaterialModule } from './myown-material.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

In the app.component.html I added a button to test the material setup like this:

```
<button mat-button>Test</button>
```

The page loads but it is just a normal button. It doesn't look like the material buttons.

What did I do wrong? I imported everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `MyOwnMaterialModule` into your **app.module.ts** and also declare it under **@NgModule's** `imports: [...]` and not the component.

Comment: Thank you. I'm quite new in angular and I forgot this step.

Comment: @user1007522 very welcome, also worth noting that you don't need to import it  into your component!

Comment: I removed it :-).